# Change the order of a sequence

Tags: java

I am trying to print a sequence using recursion without a loop. Using the code below, I get the correct output; however, it goes from large to small, and I would like it to go from small to large. What would be the best way to do that? Currently I get the output:

22 19 16 13 10

but I would like it to be reversed.

```
public class Recursion
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        sequence(5);
    }

    public static void sequence(int n)
    {
        if (n >= 1)
        {
            int x = ((3*n) + 7);
            System.out.print(x + " ");
            sequence(n-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Swap the `print` and `sequence` calls.

Answer (score 4):

Right now you print the computed value, and then you recurse with the next (decremented) n-value, which prints the next value in the sequence.

All you need to do is recurse *first*, and *then* print the current computed value after. This will print the "next" value of the sequence and *then* finish printing the just-computed "current" value.

```
public class Recursion
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        sequence(5);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void sequence(int n)
    {
        if (n >= 1)
        {
            int x = ((3*n) + 7);
            sequence(n-1);
            System.out.print(x + " ");  // changed order of recursive call and print
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a collection and reverse method like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<>();
    sequence(5,sequence);
    Collections.reverse(sequence);
    System.out.println(sequence);
  }

  public static void sequence(int n, final List<Integer> sequence) {
    if (n >= 1) {
      int x = ((3 * n) + 7);
      sequence.add(x);
      sequence(n - 1, sequence);
    }
  }
```

**Output:**

`[10, 13, 16, 19, 22]`